# sentiment analysis with ranking scale?

Tags: sentiment-analysis

I have a Customer feedback about quality of service of a bank.
I have data Excel format : header row contains the question ans, the row below contains the response of the Customer.

The responses can be textual (text responses), or numerical (scale rating).
I plan to collect all the text responses and try to do a sentiment analysis model for bank Customers reviews using R package.

My question is how to do sentiment analysis of the numerical responses?

Comment: try to limit your post to one question

Answer (score 0):

If you're using word embeddings to encode the texual responses, you could simply encode the numerical responses as an additional feature. For example, instead of having a feature vector with dimension $d$, where $d$ is the dimension of each word vector, you would append the numerical response to make a new feature vector with dimension $d+1$.